# Compare two Dataframes but just on specific columns

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have two Dataframes (df1 and df2)

```
df1: 
 A  B C  D
12 52 16 23 
19 32 30 09

df2:  
A  G  C  D  E
12 13 16 04 100
```

I want to create a new column in df1 called 'Compare'
Then I want to compare the columns 'A' and 'C' and if the are same then give 'Compare' in this row the value 'X'.

`result = df1[df1["A"].isin(df2["A"].tolist())]`
does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can chain 2 conditions with `&` for bitwise AND or `|` for bitwise OR and set new values by [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
mask = df1["A"].isin(df2["A"]) & df1["C"].isin(df2["C"])
df1['Compare'] = np.where(mask, 'X', '')
print (df1)
    A   B   C   D Compare
0  12  52  16  23       X
1  19  32  30   9
```

Or use [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with left join and `indicator=True`:

```
s = df1[['A','C']].merge(df2[['A','C']], how='left', indicator=True)['_merge']
df1['Compare'] = np.where(s == 'both', 'X', '')
print (df1)
    A   B   C   D Compare
0  12  52  16  23       X
1  19  32  30   9
```

Comment: If need `OR` use `|`